# Combining logical operators in Ruby

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I am currently working through Ruby Koans and I am faced with a situation where I want to accomplish the following:

```
if ones > 2 || twos > 2 || threes > 2 || fours > 2 || fives > 2 || sixes > 2
    #do something
end
```

Is there a better way to code this if-statement?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as below using [**Enumerable#any?**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
if [ones,twos,threes,fours,fives,sixes].any?{|e| e > 2 }
   # do something
end
```

or as **Jörg W Mittag** suggested -

```
if [ones,twos,threes,fours,fives,sixes].any?(&2.method(:<))
   # do something
end
```

Comment: You can even express this in point free style by taking advantage of the fact that `a > b == b < a` like so: `[…].any?(&2.method(:<))`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I like this style and learned it from your answer earier days..In this case I thought I would write it that way, but the point you mentioned didn't came to my mind, which is `a > b == b < a`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag keep in mind that `a > b == b < a` doesn't have to be true for **all** classes. https://gist.github.com/nedzadarek/7629711

Comment: Yes, you simply *cannot* guarantee symmetry in an object-oriented language. The receiver always gets to decide the meaning of a method call.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Enumerable#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, sixes = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
[ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, sixes].max > 2
# => true
[ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, sixes].max > 6
# => false
```

If the condition is more complex using [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) is more preferable as Arup Rakshit's answer.

Comment: Nice. `max_by` might be helpful if elements of arrays are not numeric/string values(for example hashes). With this, you can do more complex conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Enumerable#find` :

```
if [ones,twos,threes,fours,fives,sixes].find{|e| e > 2 }
   # do something
end
```

Frankly say, `Enumerable#any?` is better.